# Extracting an IP address to a variable using Expect script

Tags: expect, ifconfig

Hi I am new to Expect scripting, and I have been trying to fetch an IP address into a variable using following :

```
set timeout -1
spawn $env(SHELL)
match_max 100000
send "ifconfig | grep -A 1 'eth1' | tail -1\r "
expect -re "inet addr:.* " {send "ping $expect_out(0,string)\r"}
send -- "exit\r"
expect eof
```

The problem is that it is trying to ping with the result of the ifconfig command which has some string characters in it.

Could anyone help me to extract just IP address from the ifconfig command and store it in a variable? I have been using $expect_out(buffer) as well, but just couldn't get my head around it. Any help along these lines would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 4):

You don't need to spawn a shell:

```
spawn ifconfig eth1
expect -re {inet addr:(\S+)}
set ipaddr $expect_out(1,string)
expect eof

spawn ping -c 10 $ipaddr
expect eof
```

In fact, you don't need to use Expect: in plain Tcl (with extra error checking for ping):

```
if {[regexp {inet addr:(\S+)} [exec ifconfig eth1] -> ipaddr]} {
    set status [catch [list exec ping -c 10 $ipaddr] output]
    if {$status == 0} {
        puts "no errors from ping: $output"
    } else {
        puts "ERROR: $output"
    }
}
```

Comment: +1 I like this approach.  Is there any advantage to spawning commmands this way, as opposed to making use of exec with a 'catch' command to store the output ?  ( ie. catch { exec ping 192.168.0.1} pingresults )

Comment: It depends on how much you just have to interact with the spawned programs. If you just need it to run and you capture the output and the exit status, then use `exec`. (see [this tcl wiki article](http://wiki.tcl.tk/exec) for proper exec handling -- scroll down and click "show discussion") If the spawned program needs you to respond to prompts, then use spawn/expect/send.

Comment: Thanks- I will check the link. The interaction angle of course makes sense- maybe I was really wondering if one approach might be more 'secure' or 'safe' than the other.

Answer (score 1):

You could use [regexp](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.5/TclCmd/regexp.htm) on your existing code:

```
expect -re "inet addr:.* " {
  regexp {inet.*?(\d+\.\d+\.\d+\.\d+)} $expect_out(buffer) match ip
  puts "Pinging $ip"
  send "ping $ip\r"
}
```

In the line:

```
regexp {inet.*?(\d+\.\d+\.\d+\.\d+)} $expect_out(buffer) match ip
```

The regexp command is capturing the ip address in a bracketed 'capture group':

`(\d+\.\d+\.\d+\.\d+)`

And then storing it in the variable `ip`.

The `expect_out(buffer)` variable is the source string containing everything read so far by expect (up to your `expect -re` command), and `match` is another variable which stores a string that matches the entire regex (everything from 'inet' to the end of the ip address.)  `match` is simply there to conform to the regexp syntax of requiring a variable to be present before the capture groups- it's throwaway data in this particular example- a reworked version of regexp could use match to store the ip for this example, but in general I find capture groups more flexible, as you can have several to catch different pieces of data from a single string.

You may want to read up on the [regexp](http://wiki.tcl.tk/396) command and, [regular expressions](http://www.regular-expressions.info/) in general, as Expect makes quite extensive use of them.

Comment: Lots of thanks for your response. It works flawlessly. Could also please shed some light on what magic is going on with respect to expect(buffer) and match ip. How is match is extracting just ipaddress out of expect buffer. Please drop few lines on it. Thanks a lot for you favour.

Comment: Edited my answer to add some more detail.

Comment: Hi Thanks for a quite informative response. I got one more issue in here. the last digit of the ipaddress is getting truncated and then getting stored in the variable "ip" . For ex:  138.231.50.8 instead of  the correct one  138.231.50.80  .. Any idea why...??

Comment: Try rubular.com as a tool to tweak regular expressions.  Also make sure the $expect_out(buffer) is populated with all the data it needs, it's possible your expect -re statement is matching before the whole line is printed to stdout.  Use a puts statement to troubleshoot it.

Answer (score 0):

Change your 'send `"ifconfig | grep -A 1 'en1' | tail -1\r"` to look like the below line instead.

`send "ifconfig | grep -A 1 'en1' | tail -1 | cut -d' ' -f2\r"`

Answer (score 0):

```
$ifconfig 
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:1b:fc:72:84:12  
      inet addr:172.16.1.13  Bcast:172.16.1.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
      inet6 addr: fe80::21b:fcff:fe72:8412/64 Scope:Link
      UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
      RX packets:638661 errors:0 dropped:20 overruns:0 frame:0
      TX packets:93858 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:2
      collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
      RX bytes:101655955 (101.6 MB)  TX bytes:42802760 (42.8 MB)
      Memory:dffc0000-e0000000 

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
      inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
      inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
      UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:16436  Metric:1
      RX packets:3796 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
      TX packets:3796 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
      collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
      RX bytes:517624 (517.6 KB)  TX bytes:517624 (517.6 KB)
```

try this:

```
ifconfig | sed '2,2!d' | sed 's/.*addr://' | sed 's/\ .*//' > ipaddress
```

this will give ip

```
$vi ipaddress
```